java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils does not have member field 'java.lang.Character ESCAPE_CHARACTER'
After the update to spring boot 3.4.0 I started to get this error:
    12:54:11.255 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils does not have member field 'java.lang.Character ESCAPE_CHARACTER'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.get(Binder.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.get(Binder.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.<init>(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigDataEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350)
    at com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.batchreference.batch.AnalysisApplication.main(AnalysisApplication.java:17)
    at com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.batchreference.batch.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:13)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils does not have member field 'java.lang.Character ESCAPE_CHARACTER'
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:823)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:328)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350)
    at com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.batchreference.batch.AnalysisApplication.main(AnalysisApplication.java:17)
    at com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.batchreference.batch.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils does not have member field 'java.lang.Character ESCAPE_CHARACTER'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.get(Binder.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.get(Binder.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.<init>(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigDataEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    ... 4 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56343', transport: 'socket'

Spring is attempting to access a field ESCAPE_CHARACTER in the SystemPropertyUtils class. But this field does not exist.
As I understood there is mismatch between versions of spring libraries, but I cant figure out between which ones exactly. Here is my POM.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.jsf.fem</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.jsf.fem</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-batch</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.13-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <batch.app>JSF-BATCH-PROCESSING</batch.app>
    <batch.dir>batch-processing</batch.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <acts-activity-service-v4-client-cxf.version>1.0.2</acts-activity-service-v4-client-cxf.version>
    <immutables.version>2.10.1</immutables.version>
    <break.jinja.rederer.version>2.2.0</break.jinja.rederer.version>
    <jackson.guava.version>2.18.2</jackson.guava.version>
    <break.rest.common.version>5.0.5</break.rest.common.version>
    <spring.boot.version>3.4.0</spring.boot.version>
    <jml.token>cc47b1079128a170a30a4666e3d6310ed59d1e7dd3b8736b73a2b7c6</jml.token>
  </properties>


  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lls.liability.break</groupId>
      <artifactId>break-jinja-renderer</artifactId>
      <version>${break.jinja.rederer.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>break-rest-common-client-restesb</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.lls.fs.break</groupId>
      <version>${break.rest.common.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>break-rest-common-responses</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.lls.fs.break</groupId>
      <version>${break.rest.common.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
      <artifactId>value</artifactId>
      <version>${immutables.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGBACK -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
      <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lls.fs.tac.lbe</groupId>
      <artifactId>tac-lbe</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lls.fs.break.wsclients.external</groupId>
      <artifactId>acts-activity-service-v4-client-cxf</artifactId>
      <version>${acts-activity-service-v4-client-cxf.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jakarta -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.interceptor-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20230227</version> 

    <!-- Oracle -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.nls</groupId>
      <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.ha</groupId>
      <artifactId>simplefan</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.ha</groupId>
      <artifactId>ons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>assemble</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <binFileExtensions>
                <unix>.sh</unix>
              </binFileExtensions>
              <environmentSetupFileName>env.sh</environmentSetupFileName>
              <platforms>
                <platform>unix</platform>
              </platforms>
              <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
              <programs>
                <program>
                  <mainClass>com.lls.fs.break.ecp.batchreference.batch.AnalysisApplication</mainClass>
                  <id>commandLineRunner</id>
                </program>
              </programs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>jml-distribution.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lls.fs.tac.jml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>upload</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>upload</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>


Mixing incompatible versions. Add the full stacktrace instead of just a snippet.

@M.Deinum sure, updated the question with the full stacktrace

The field it complains about has been added in Spring 6.2 which is what Spring Boot 3.4 uses and expects. Some of your dependencies (probably managed by your parent) is pulling in older versions. Run mvn dependency:tree to see what is pulling in what.

the older version was pulled from the parent, thanks

@JavaGeek what was the exact change you had to do?

I have downgreded from spring boot 3.4 to 3.3.7 e.g. <parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> <version>3.3.7</version> </parent>
